# Laravel post MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm getting the error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

when I change my page to use `POST` instead of `GET`.
I know there are alot of questions about this but every single one has a different right answer. I've seen someone say: `you are POSTing to a GET route.` on a different question, but thats not the case here.

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','files'=>true)) }}
```

and I also changed the route:

```
Route::post('page', 'UserController@page');
```

Im not doing anything with other pages.
I changed all the `Input::get` to `Input::post` even though I've heard `Input::get` can also be used with `POST`

What am I forgetting here?

Comment: You don't have an action on your form open. I'm not sure what it defaults to, be it the same path as the page you're on, or a `/` for example perhaps. Check there's a POST route for whatever the `action` is on your `<form>` element

Comment: Post your routes file

Comment: You may try this {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.page')) }} and see if it works

Comment: @TheShiftExchange there's only 1 line in routes I use in this case? I editted the question.

Comment: If you only have one route then you're likely getting the exception because you're visiting a POST route with GET. For example you need both `Route::get('page'...)` and `Route::post('page',...)`. The former being used when you access the URL to see the form, and the latter when you submit it.

Comment: @BenSwinburne So I have to have `Route::post('page', 'UserController@page');` and `Route::get('page', 'UserController@page');`?

Comment: You can use any method Route::any('page', 'UserController@page');

Comment: @BenSwinburne When I do that. I get: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()

Comment: @Loko `Input::post()` doesn't exist. All params are retrieved with `Input::get()` even if the method is POST

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yup thanks that fixed it after I got both `Route::post('page', 'UserController@page');` and `Route::get('page', 'UserController@page2');` in my routes